# Play upgrade from 2.3 to 2.6

Tags: java, playframework

I am trying to update and existing play project from 2.3 to 2.6 .
I did routing changes and remove methods of GlobalSetting.java.
But now when i am using JPA.withTransaction() or with JPAApi,I am getting a compile time error 'can not find the symbol withTransaction ' or 'JPAApi'.

here is my build.sbt file

```
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  filters,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  evolutions,
  guice,
  javaJpa.exclude("org.hibernate.javax.persistence", "hibernate-jpa-
  2.0-api"),
  "org.eclipse.persistence" % "eclipselink" % "2.5.2",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.34",
  "com.auth0" % "java-jwt" % "2.0.0",
  "be.objectify" %% "deadbolt-java" % "2.3.1",
  "javax.inject" % "javax.inject" % "1",
  "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.3",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "2.4.0",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.6.0",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-iteratees" % "2.6.1",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-iteratees-reactive-streams" % "2.6.1",
  "org.apache.jclouds.provider" % "rackspace-clouddns-us" % "1.9.0",
  "org.apache.jclouds.labs" % "rackspace-cloudfiles-us" % "1.9.0",
  "org.apache.jclouds.api" % "openstack-swift" % "1.9.0",
  "org.apache.poi" % "poi" % "3.9",
  "org.apache.poi" % "poi-ooxml" % "3.9",
  "com.itextpdf" % "itextpdf" % "5.5.9",
  "com.itextpdf.tool" % "xmlworker" % "5.5.9",
  "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.2.4",
  "com.typesafe" % "play-plugins-mailer_2.9.1" % "2.0.4",
  "commons-logging" % "commons-logging" % "1.1.1",
  "commons-httpclient" % "commons-httpclient" % "3.1",
  "com.paypal.sdk" % "paypal-core" % "1.7.0",
  "com.sun.jersey" % "jersey-core" % "1.19",
  "org.json" % "json" % "20151123",
  "org.apache.cxf" % "cxf-bundle" % "2.6.3",
  "commons-codec" % "commons-codec" % "1.8",
  "com.unboundid" % "unboundid-ldapsdk" % "2.3.3",
  "com.paypal.sdk" % "rest-api-sdk" % "0.7.0",
  "com.paypal.sdk" % "merchantsdk" % "2.14.117",
  "org.apache.neethi" % "neethi" % "3.0.3",
  "com.opencsv" % "opencsv" % "3.7",
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.3.11",
  "com.jolbox" % "bonecp" % "0.8.0.RELEASE"
 )

resolvers += Resolver.url("Objectify Play Repository", 
url("http://deadbolt.ws/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

javaOptions in Test += "-
Dconfig.file=scorm.conf/application.test.scorm.conf"

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator


PlayKeys.externalizeResources := false
```

Here is my plugin.sqt file

```
 resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at 
"https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.6.0")

// web plugins

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.0.0")

libraryDependencies += "log4j" % "log4j" % "1.2.14"
```

Comment: Which `withTransaction` method we're talking about? There's a few.

Comment: None of the `withTransaction` method is working . I am using
 `public static <T> F.Promise<T> withTransactionAsync(play.libs.F.Function0<F.Promise<T>> block)`  this method.

I tried with `JPAApi` also but `JPAApi` is also giving error like 'can not find symbol JPAApi'